# {% with %} tag to store 'in' expression value in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to store a boolean value in a variable within the **{% with %}** tag of Django. But its not working. is there any other way around to do this ? Can I create a custom filter for it or is there any pre-built filter for this?

```
{% with isEnrolled=course in all_courses %}
   .....
 {% endwith %}
```

Comment: why dont you use a for loop?

Comment: I want to store a boolean value in a variable 'isEnrolled'. True if the 'course' is present in the list 'all_courses' else False